# Django rest_framework, logout redirect doesnt work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-login

I am trying to redirect to the home page after clicking on Logout

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        .
        .
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),
]
```

settigs.py

```
   .
   .
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

The problem is it still redirect to `/api-auth/logout/?next=/current-page`. This causes an error because this "current page" needs authentication (requires a login) unlike the home page which doesn't require a login

I also tried `path("api-auth/logout", RedirectView.as_view(url="/", permanent=True))` but this again didn't work(still redirected to the "current page").

How can I redirect to the home page?

Answer (score 1):

Just add code below to your settings.py.

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'LOGIN_URL': 'rest_framework:login',
    'LOGOUT_URL': 'rest_framework:logout'
}
```